# Trying to Filter and display last 10 results

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to retrieve the last 10 mentions of the text that's in cell B8.

For example, if B8 is "Tom Brady", I want to retrieve the last 10 results for Passing Yards (DB:M) that mention Tom Brady.

I got this formula but it displays the first 15 it seems.
=QUERY(DB!B:AZ,"select M where C = '"&B8&"' order by B desc limit 15")

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12b9dxeSt4_F9hdgaqDzggNW-fbMyXesWaqT0JjqMVhk/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SORTN(FILTER({D5:D, ROW(D5:D)}, D5:D<>""), 10, 0, 2, 0), 2, 1),,1)
```

[image]